# Определить границы невыгружаемого пула ядра

Tags: c, windows, kernel, драйвер

Встала задача пробежать по non-paged пулу в Windows? Но где ее начало и конец - непонятно. Пока в голове только такой вариант: выделить небольшой участок через `ExAllocatePoolWithTag`,а от него бежать вверх и вниз по памяти, пока `MmIsAddressValid(address) == TRUE`, но ловлю синий экран `driver_irql_not_less_or_equal`. Кто, может, сталкивался, как это реализовать?

Comment: Все решилось. Удалять пока не буду, вдруг кому интересно - опишу решение.

Comment: Конечно, интересно. Рассказывайте!

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю сам, так как все-таки разобрался.
Задача более конкретно стояла такая: найти некоторую функцию по ее отпечатку (не спрашивайте, зачем:) ), причем хотелось, чтобы всё это не зависело от текущей ОС, поэтому пришло следующее решение:

1. С помощью функции `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` выделяем память в Non-Paged области ядра. Функция возвращает тип PVOID, таким образом мы получили адрес, который гарантированно находятся где-то в нужной области. То есть невыгружаемый пул в обе стороны от этого адреса.
2. В цикле пробегаем в обе стороны, по условию `MmIsAddressValid` для текущего адреса и для `текущего + sizeof(ULONG64)` (именно поэтому получал BSOD с `driver_irql_not_less_or_equal`), так как для каждого адреса осуществляется приведение к `ULONG64`.
3. Для ускорения процесса воспользовался функцией `KeIpiGenericCall` - позволяет задействовать все активные процессоры. То есть каждый процессор сканирует свой участок памяти.

Код примерно такой:

```
Function1(ULONG_PTR argument)
{
    LONG processorNumber;
    ULONG processorsCount;
    KIRQL oldIrql;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(argument);

    processorNumber = KeGetCurrentProcessorNumber();    
    processorsCount = KeQueryActiveProcessorCount(NULL);

    KeRaiseIrql(HIGH_LEVEL, &oldIrql);

    //Вот финт с параллельностью: проверяется со смещением в количество процессоров
    //а начинается для каждого процессора со своего адреса, тогда для 2-хядерной системы
    //первое ядро будет сканировать 1,3,5,... а второе - 2,4,6,...
    Function2(StartSearchAddress + processorNumber, processorsCount);
    Function2(StartSearchAddress - processorNumber, (-1)*processorsCount);

    KeLowerIrql(oldIrql);
}

Function2(PUCHAR startAddress, int offset)
{
    PUCHAR checkingAddress = startAddress;
    ULONG64 value; 

    while (MmIsAddressValid(checkingAddress) && MmIsAddressValid(checkingAddress + sizeof(ULONG64)))
    {
        value = *((PULONG64)checkingAddress);
        //здесь по необходимости действия с value
    }
```